# Best practice to test if any empty field

Tags: cucumber

I have a form with 7 input fields.

The scenario is that I want to test if any field missing, the system should prompt an error for the missing one.

So I make following feature:

```
  Scenario: Sending request with an empty form
    Then I fill in "Phone" with "979000000"
    And I fill in "Name" with "John"
    And I fill in "Email" with "john@mail.me"
    And I fill in "Circumstance" with "Trash outside"
    And I fill in "Address" with "700 University Dr. E"
    And I fill in "Start Date" with "10/31/2014"
    And I fill in "End Date" with "11/01/2014"
    When I press "Submit request"
    Then I should see prompt for all missing fields
```

and then one by one remove a field and make a new scenario.

This is obviously not a good practice. Is there any good way to test all fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Scenario Outline to make only "one" scenario

```
Scenario Outline: Sending request with an uncomplete form
  Given/when I am on the form...
  When I fill the form with datas :
  | name   | email   | circumstance   | address   | start   | end   |
  | <name> | <email> | <circumstance> | <address> | <start> | <end> |
  When I press "Submit request"
  Then I should see prompt for missing field: <missing>

  Scenarios:
  | name | email        | circumstance  | address              | start      | end        | missing |
  |      | john@mail.me | Trash outside | 700 University Dr. E | 10/31/2014 | 11/01/2014 | name    |
  | john |              | Trash outside | 700 University Dr. E | 10/31/2014 | 11/01/2014 | email   |
  | john | john@mail.me | Trash outside | 700 University Dr. E | 10/31/2014 |            | end     |
```

Outline make your scenario played several times: one for each line of "scenarios"

Then you need to make your steps to fill all non empty datas.

```
When(/^I fill the form with datas :$/) do | table |
  datas = table.hashes.first
  datas.each do |label, value|
    if !value.empty?
      @browser.text_field(name: label).set value
    end
  end
end
```

And then, you can add examples with several empty fields and check several fields with the value "missing".

Answer (score 2):

Cucumber is not a tool for doing exhaustive testing.

If you want to test that your model validates the prescence of each field, use a unit test. This will be faster to run and easier to implement.

If you want to show that the mechanism for prompting you to fill in empty fields is working, do this for just one field (you know it works for other fields, because of your unit test).

Write a feature something like

```
Scenario: Incomplete form
  When I fill in the form
  And I leave a required field empy
  Then I should see a missing field prompt
```

One way to think about this is don't waste time testing platform code, instead concentrate on testing your applications code.